# Training a network on two feature vectors?

Tags: deep-learning, feature-engineering

I want to train an MLP that takes in two nba teams `A` and `B` and classifies one as a winner and the other as a loser (probably binary classification 0 for loser 1 for winner) as well as a predictor that assigns a probability that team `A` wins vs team `B`. I'm having trouble figuring out how the feature vector should look though and would like some advice. My ideas are

1. Take the difference between each team's feature
2. Concatenate the featers IE for one training example it would be `[A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,...,A_n,B_n]` where `n` is the feature number
3. Use one feature vector for each team?(Don't know if that works)

Could anyone give somee suggestions

Comment: Try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Scott Hunter to try everything, here are a few thoughts:

1. Taking the difference - this depends very much on what the team's features represent. If each feature is like a statistic of the team (such as win rate, etc), then taking the difference might work. If it is something more abstract, it may not be a good idea. But you can try.
2. Concatenate the features - I think this would be a good choice, at least when starting out. It definitely seems the most obvious, and I think it would work to a good extent.

Another approach: You could build an encoder, which takes the team's feature vector and outputs a condensed representation. Then, you can do something with this condensed representation (feed it to a simpler model, or another MLP as well).